# How to work animation in android TV Box

Tags: android-animation, android-tv

I am developing application for Android TV. For debugging, I am using `Xiomi Android TV Box`. I want to show a dialog box with enter animation and exit animation. For achieve requirement I am using below code.

Activity

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Animation Dialog");
                builder.setMessage("type");
                builder.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.CustomDialogTheme;
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Styles.xml file

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDialogTheme">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/spin_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/spin_out</item>
    </style>
```

When we deploy this code on `Android Mobile` or `Amazon Fire TV`, then animation work perfectly, but when we deploy this code on `Xiomi Android Tv Box` Animation is not working.
Why animation is not working on `Xiomi Android TV box` and how can we animate dialog box in `Xiomi Android TV box`?

After many research I found that there is a option in Xiomi Android Tv box to ON and OFF Animation that is available on `Settings>developer option>drawing>Window animation scale.`

Can it possible to do Animation ON and OFF of Xiomi Android TV box that is available on `Settings>developer option>drawing>Window animation scale`?

Comment: Please also post your logs. Did you probably get a warning like this: 'W/art: Verification of void xxx(your clicklistener) took 123ms'?

Comment: @SimonTenbeitel, I did not get warning like W/art: Verification of void xxx... and there is not log print during click event